# Static library files shows linker error

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added a static library through add target option in xcode. Now I have moved some common files to this library.But it shows "_OBJC_CLASS_$_", referenced from:objc-class-ref in 
error. I have added all .m files in that library in compile sources now what wrong I have done on it?? Is there any additional settings needed in .pch file or somewhere else??

Comment: Voted to close as **Unclear what you're asking** and **Demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you have done, it seems you have forgot to link your static library to your main program.

In order to fix this (if my hypothesis is correct):

1. go to your main target properties;
2. select Build Phases;
3. open the first section "Target Dependencies" and add your target there (by clicking on th `+` icon);
4. open the "Link binary with libraries" section and do the same.

Hope this helps.